# How to update multiple columns in the oracle SQL on ATP fusion DB

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I am trying to use the below query, its everytime saying cannot insert null for the second column.

```
 UPDATE TABLE1 
    SET (COL1,COL2,COL3) = (SELECT COL1,COL2,COL3 
                              FROM TABLE2
                             WHERE t1.id = t2.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE TABLE1 SET (COL1,COL2,COL3) =
     (SELECT COL1,NVL(COL2,0),COL3 FROM TABLE1 T1, TABLE2 T2 where t1.id = t2.id)
     WHERE <YOUR WHERE CONDITION>
```

Comment: Actually col2 is not null we had a value for it still throwing an error.

Comment: UPDATE TABLE1 SET (COL1,COL3,COL2) =
     (SELECT COL1,COL3,COL2 FROM TABLE1 T1, TABLE2 T2 where t1.id = t2.id)
     WHERE <YOUR WHERE CONDITION>                                                                                       if I tried this way then error is throwing saying col3 cant be null

Comment: then try nvl(col3,0) instead of just writing col3 in the select statement like we did for col2

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `MERGE`:

```
MERGE INTO TABLE1 t1
USING (SELECT id, COL1,COL2,COL3 
         FROM TABLE2) t2
   ON (t1.id = t2.id)
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET t1.COL1 = t2.COL1
                            , t1.COL2 = t2.COL2
                            , t1.COL3 = t2.COL3;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are rows in `table1` where not corresponding row exists in `table2` thus the sub-query returns nothing which means the UPDATE statement will take that as `null` for all three columns.

You have to add a WHERE clause that only updates rows in `table1` that do have a matching row in `table2`

```
UPDATE TABLE1 
    SET (COL1,COL2,COL3) = (SELECT COL1,COL2,COL3 
                            FROM TABLE2 t2
                            WHERE table1.id = t2.id)
where exist (select * 
             from table2 t2
             where table1.id = t2.id);
```